# Problem using javascript to schedule function on Chrome console

Tags: javascript

I have this `function` I use to copy elements from a webpage on `Chrome Console` (web scraping), but when I try to repeat it with `setInterval`, it just doesn't run. There is no `error message` or something, but alerts at the end of each option do not show.

```
setInterval(function() {
    try {
        var lobby = [{}];
        lobby[0]['1'] = document.querySelector("#root > div > div.app-container > div.lobby.lobby_floating.lobby-enter-done > div.lobby__body > div.lobby__container > div > div > div.common-scroll__scroll-view > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.lobby-table__container > div.lobby-table-history.lobby-table-history_game-rol.lobby-table-history_type-numb").innerText;
        lobby[0]['2'] = document.querySelector("#root > div > div.app-container > div.lobby.lobby_floating.lobby-enter-done > div.lobby__body > div.lobby__container > div > div > div.common-scroll__scroll-view > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.lobby-table__container > div.lobby-table-history.lobby-table-history_game-rol.lobby-table-history_type-numb > div").innerText;
        copy(lobby);
        alert('1');
    } catch (err) {
        var lobby = [{}];
        lobby[0]['1'] = document.querySelector("#root > div > div.app-container > div.lobby.lobby_external > div.lobby__body > div.lobby__container > div > div > div.common-scroll__scroll-view > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.lobby-table__container > div.lobby-table-history.lobby-table-history_game-rol.lobby-table-history_type-numb").innerText;
        lobby[0]['2'] = document.querySelector("#root > div > div.app-container > div.lobby.lobby_external > div.lobby__body > div.lobby__container > div > div > div.common-scroll__scroll-view > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.lobby-table__container > div.lobby-table-history.lobby-table-history_game-rol.lobby-table-history_type-numb > div").innerText;
        copy(lobby);
        alert('2');
    }
}, 1000);
```

One option would be to save that var into a txt file, but I would be happy just by updating and copying the var from time to time.

Thank you guys

Comment: Can you show your call to setInterval?

Comment: Where's the set interval you're trying?

Comment: Some browsers will block pages from showing multiple alerts. I would get rid of the alerts and just do a console log instead to see if the that code in your function is actually executing. Give that a try, otherwise as the others have said post a bit more of your code as it's hard to tell exactly what's going on with what you have here.

Comment: @Marvin and Caleb Jay I updated the post with the call to setInterval, sorry about that.

Comment: @TheOneTrueColter About the alerts, I am using it just to check if its working, but its not. When I clean all the function and let just the setInterval calling for the alert its totally working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fine in my [simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLovfe2s/2/).

```js
setInterval(function() {
    try {
        var lobby = [{}];
        lobby[0]['1'] = document.querySelector("#root > div.lobby-table-history").innerText;
        lobby[0]['2'] = document.querySelector("#root > div ").innerText;
        copy(lobby);
        console.log('1');
    } catch (err) {
        var lobby = [{}];
        lobby[0]['1'] = document.querySelector("#root > div.lobby-table-history").innerText;
        lobby[0]['2'] = document.querySelector("#root > div").innerText;
        copy(lobby);
        console.log('2');
    }
}, 1000);

function copy() {

}
```

```html
<div id = "root">
<div>

</div>
<div class = "lobby-table-history">

</div>
</div>
```

Using this code, it logs "1" indefinitely. I predict that you have a bug in your `copy()` function and something there is leading the `setInterval()` function to terminate.

Comment: Sure, but the code runs well without the serInterval thing. 
Do you think it is maybe chrome stopping me to run this on console?

It its the problem, there's any way for me to do it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with web scraping, but I think you should 1) replace alert with console.log and 2) Review your copy function because that's the only other JavaScript component that I left empty